# Stop touchend firing links unintentionally

Tags: jquery, ios, touch-event

I'm using the `touchend`event to prevent ios from requiring two touches to fire `href` links.
This works fine however it is firing the links unintentionally when scrolling.

I know that the the solution is to implement the `touchstart` to see if there is movement, but I'm a jquery novice and I'm not sure how apply this.

Here is the `touchend`code

```
$('a').on('touchend', function(e) {
var el = $(this);
var link = el.attr('href');
window.location = link;
});
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok this is what is working for me to solve this using code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690620/checking-if-touchend-comes-after-a-drag)

```
var dragging = false;
$("a").on("touchmove", function(){
  dragging = true;
});

$("a").on("touchend", function(e){
  if (dragging){
e.preventDefault();
}
else {var el = $(this);
var link = el.attr('href');
window.location = link;
}    

});

$("a").on("touchstart", function(){
dragging = false;
});
```

This works for me.

Comment: Nice solution! Just remember that jQuery doesn't always simply things. In the `else` statement on `touchend` you can do the redirect like this: `window.location = this.href;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/preventDefault/):

```
$('a').on('touchend', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var el = $(this);
var link = el.attr('href');
window.location = link;
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid. It still fires the link unintentionally if you touch a link when scrolling. You can see here: http://dev2014.rab.co.uk/

Comment: how about touchstart? just replace touchend to touchstart.

Comment: No touchstart fires the link immediately when clicked where as touchend fires the link after the scroll has stopped. I'm guessing there needs to be an if statement that checks if there has been movement and stops the link from firing?

Comment: You need to detect if they are dragging. You can do this by setting a flag on `touchstart`. Credit to @CoreyHarrison

Answer (score 0):

For me this one works

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    if (link !== undefined && link !== '') {
        window.location = link;
    }
});
```