# Prevent click event in <a> tags when scrolling in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events, triggers

I'm starting a website, http://alfstyle.com and have an issue when scrolling down in my phone. The click event from the  tags fires unintentionally. It is so frustating.

I have tried deactivating plugins, jQuery, some scripts, etc.. and nothing works.

[I've made a screenshot where the issue begins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Z9H.png)

I tried prevent the redirection with snippets of javascript that I found here:
[Stop touchend firing links unintentionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451908/stop-touchend-firing-links-unintentionally)

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally whet scrolling on mobile websites not activate links like on your webpage. The reason why is happening its because of additional code injected to page. I have found a part of code which make unneded window.location change.

```
function toggleSubmenuDisplay() {

   document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

    if ( event.target.matches('a') ) {

        var url = event.target.getAttribute( 'href' ) ? event.target.getAttribute( 'href' ) : '';

        // If there’s a link, go to it on touchend
        if ( '#' !== url && '' !== url ) {
            window.location = url;

        // Open submenu if url is #
        }
        ...
     }
```

The code currently is attached to all touchstart actions. When touching on mobile this handler is executed and also this part is executed:

```
if ( '#' !== url && '' !== url ) {
    window.location = url;
}
```

If you will place debugger here you will see that this code is executed.

Also remove this script, It couse redirecting on touchend gesture:

```
 $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        var link = el.attr('href');
        if (link !== undefined && link !== '') {
            window.location = link;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Łukasz Blaszyński. You are my saviour. I deactivate that .js and works fine now.